# differential eq - general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find a general solution for this equation

$xy'=y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I got $\tan\frac{y}{x}+\sec\frac{y}{x} = x + c$ as an answer.

I substituted $y=vx$ and it led me to the trig-related answer.

The answer sheet gives $y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = Cx^2$.

I honestly how to derive this. Can I get some help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{y}{x}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$$
$$u=\frac{y}{x}$$
$$u+xu'=u+\sqrt{1+u^2}$$
Separable ODE :
$$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln|x[+c_1=\int\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=\sinh^{-1}(u)+c_2$$
$$u=\sinh\left(\ln|cx[\right)=\frac12\left(cx-\frac{1}{cx}\right)$$
$$y=\frac12\left(cx^2-\frac{1}{c}\right)$$
$x^2=\frac{2}{c}y+\frac{1}{c^2}\quad;\quad x^2+y^2=\frac{2}{c}y+\frac{1}{c^2}+y^2=\left(y+\frac{1}{c}\right)^2$

$y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=y+(y+\frac{1}{c})=2y+\frac{1}{c}=\left(cx^2-\frac{1}{c}\right)+\frac{1}{c}$
$$y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=cx^2$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. One quick question: how did you make $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to $\sqrt{1+(\frac{y}{x}}$? Would you give me the name for the 'rule' you used, so I can look it up?

Comment: oh wait nevermind!

Answer (score 2):

You can play a bit with the terms and get$$x^2\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'= xy'-y = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \lvert x \rvert \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}.$$
Define $y(x)/x =: z(x)$, then you have
$$z' = \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{x^2}\sqrt{1+z^2} $$
and separating variables
$$\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} = \int\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{x^2}\,dx$$
Putting $z = \sinh w$ yields $\sqrt{1+z^2} = \cosh w$ and $dz = \cosh w \,dw$, so 
\begin{align}\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}=\int \frac{\cosh w}{ \cosh w} dw & = w  = \sinh^{-1}z \\
& = \log (z+\sqrt{1+z^2})
\end{align} 
up to a constant $c$. Then
\begin{align}
\log (z+\sqrt{1+z^2}) & = \text{sgn}\{x\}\left(\log \lvert x\rvert + \log e^c\right)  \\
& = \log (C\lvert x \rvert)^{\text{sgn}\{x\}}, \text{ with }C > 0,
\end{align}
and finally, since $z(x)=y(x)/x$ you compare the arguments of the logarithms getting
$$\frac{y}{x}+ \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = (C\lvert x\rvert)^{\text{sgn}\{x\}}. $$
This solution does not depend on the sign of $x$ (just try to explicit $y$ when $x > 0$ and $x < 0$ and you will get the same expression). So the solution for $x > 0$ gives the result:
$$y +\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = Cx^2.$$